# equivalence relations divides sets into partitions whose union is the set but if some elements of the set aren't in the relation how does this work?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations, set-partition

The proposition given is:- every equivalence relation induces a partition
of the underlying set, the parts of the partition being the equivalence
classes, i.e. the equivalence classes are pair-wise disjoint subsets
whose union is the whole set.

Take a set $A = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and a relation on $A$, $R = \{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(a,c),(c,a)\}$.
$R$ is equivalent because it's reflexive, symmetric and transitive.
$R$ will only give the equivalent classes $[a]$, $[b]$ and $[c]$ which are $\{a,c\}$ and $\{b\}$.
the union of these equivalent classes is $\{a,b,c\}$ which is not equal to $A$ so how does the above proposition work?

Comment: That's not an equivalence relation.  For that, you need $x\sim x$ for all $x$.

Comment: so all elements of the set are required to be a part of the relation?

Comment: Each element of the set is required to be related to itself. This is required for the relation to be reflexive. In your example, you need to add $(d,d)$ and $(e,e)$ to the set $R$ to make the relation reflexive.